# I vs Me from SAT question

Tags: pronouns

Here is my example (from an SAT question):

> No one is sorrier than I that you missed the awards ceremony

I don't know understand why it is "I". Shouldn't it be "me" since "I" is the subject here? Thanks

Comment: It's due to inadequate analysis on the part of whoever came up with the question.

Comment: @sumelic They appear to be saying that *me* is an incorrect choice, but of course it's fine.  Maybe I read too much into the question . . . ?

Comment: @snailboat: from the answers below, it looks like this question only requires you to recognize that "I" is valid here; you don't have to say that "me" is incorrect, because it is not given as an option.

Comment: @dngr193 What are the choices the question gives?

Answer (score 2):

If "I" is the subject, then you should be using "I."  If "I" were the object, you should use "me."

http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/blog/english-mistakes/i-vs-me/

In this case it's weird, because of the sentence structure.  I get my head around it by filling in the implied "No one is sorrier than **I Am** that..."

That implied "am" makes all the difference.  It's clearly wrong to say "No one is sorrier than me am."

Also, if you're taking it from a practice test...

> practice test #6 section 6 of the blue book. It's #4: No one is [more sorrier than me] that you missed the awards ceremony. (A) more sorrier than me (B) sorrier than I (C) more sorry like myself (D) as sorry like I am **(E) sorrier but me**

It looks like the "me" option (E) is incorrect because of "but."
(http://qa.pwnthesat.com/post/57707656637/i-need-help-with-a-writing-question-improving)

Comment: I see, that post was very useful

Answer (score 2):

The given sentence suggests that "than" is a conjunction, linking the two sentences "I am sorry" with "no one is sorrier".

In full, the sentence would be "no one is sorrier than I *am* that you missed the awards ceremony". The "am" is implied and understood; it's left out through [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

However, there is an argument for using "me" instead of "I". Such a construction would would suggest that "than" is a preposition.

You can read about the controversy [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/than-i-versus-than-me).

If you want a rule of thumb without any real explanation, go [here](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/better-than-I-or-better-than-me).

If you want a historical take on the grammar controversy, you can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement#Disputed_pronoun_forms).